# Integrating over an area defined by an inequality

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, inequality

I am attempting to solve the following integral

$\iint_{C} (x^2+y^2)dx dy$ where $C = \{(x,y):-1 \leq x = y \leq 1\}$

What area is this inequality describing?

I am also supposed to integrate the same integral over $C = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$

How do I do this integral?

Also - is there an online resource that would explain this topic. These kinds of inequalities are coming up frequently in my statistics course.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use Fubini's theorem: first integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $-1$ to $y$ and then integrate w.r.t. $y$ from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: I believe that $x=y$ should in fact be $x,y$.

Comment: there is an equal sign in the book and it gives the answer as 0 for that problem, I just can't figure out how they got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) $C = \{(x,y):-1 \leq x=y \leq 1\}$ is a the diagonal of the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and
$$\iint_{C} (x^2+y^2)dx dy=\int_{x=-1}^1\left(\int_{y=x}^x (x^2+y^2)dy\right) dx=\int_{x=-1}^1\left([x^2y+y^3/3]_{y=x}^x\right) dx\\
=\int_{x=-1}^1 0\ dx=0.$$

1') $C = \{(x,y):-1 \leq x , y \leq 1\}$ is the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ and
$$\iint_{C} (x^2+y^2)dx dy=\int_{x=-1}^1\left(\int_{y=-1}^1 (x^2+y^2)dy\right) dx=\int_{x=-1}^1\left([x^2y+y^3/3]_{y=-1}^1\right) dx\\
=\int_{x=-1}^1(2x^2+2/3) dx=[2x^3/3+2/3x]_{x=-1}^1 =8/3.$$

2) $C = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ is the disc centred at $(0,0)$ of radius $1$ and
$$\iint_{C} (x^2+y^2)dx dy=\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\rho=0}^{1} \rho^2 \cdot \rho d\rho d\theta=[\theta]_{\theta=0}^{2\pi}\cdot[\rho^4/4]_{\rho=0}^1=2\pi/4=\pi/2$$
where we used the polar coordinates.

Comment: thank you, but the problem is from -1 <= x = y <= 1 and the book gives the answer as 0, I just can't figure out how.

Comment: @Eliza Sorry, I was not sure of your definition of $C$. The double  integral of a continuous function on segment is zero. I included the details in my answer.